# Example of Sorting a Firemonkey StringGrid

Tags: delphi, sorting, firemonkey, tstringgrid

My basic attempt at sorting a Firemonkey Stringgrid, as couldn't find any other examples.  I would welcome any optimisations or other suggestions on best achieving this.  My code basically gets the column chosen to sort and with that sort order completes for other columns:

```
procedure TfrmMain.StringGridSort(StrGrid: TStringGrid; SortColumn: Integer);
var
  col, row, rowx: Integer;
  MySortCol, MyListCols: TStringList;
begin
  MySortCol := TStringList.Create;
  MyListCols := TStringList.Create;
  try
    MySortCol.Sort;
    MyListCols.Sorted := False;
    StrGrid.BeginUpdate;
    try
      for row := 0 to StrGrid.RowCount - 1 do
        MySortCol.AddObject(StrGrid.Cells[SortColumn, row], TObject(row));
      MySortCol.Sorted := True;
      for row := 0 to StrGrid.RowCount - 1 do
        StrGrid.Cells[SortColumn, row] := MySortCol[row];

      for col := 0 to StrGrid.ColumnCount - 1 do
        if col <> SortColumn then
        begin
          MyListCols.Clear;
          for row := 0 to StrGrid.RowCount - 1 do
            MyListCols.Add(StrGrid.Cells[col, row]);

          for rowx := 0 to StrGrid.RowCount - 1 do
            StrGrid.Cells[col, rowx] :=
              MyListCols[Integer(MySortCol.Objects[rowx])];
        end;
    finally
      StrGrid.EndUpdate;
    end;
  finally
    MySortCol.Free;
    MyListCols.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Thanks in advance Paul

Comment: I'm no stringgrid expert but you'll probably want to wrap everything in Grid.BeginUpdate ... Grid.EndUpdate calls for the best performance.

Comment: @MikeSutton - Oops, that's a bit embarrassing - added.  Thanks Paul